# Using .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having some mod_rewrite problems with my .htaccess..

```
RewriteBase /folder

RewriteEngine on
Rewrit­eRule ^(.*)$ basic.p­hp?­url=$1 [L]
```

Above is what I'm currently using. However, I have no idea what I'm doing to be honest as I'm just cycling through the internet trying to figure this out.

Basically, for my website, if you type in

```
www.domain.com/folder/xxx/
```

I want it to basically be `www.domain.com/folder/basic.php?url=xxx`.
For some reason, all that does is cause a 404 error :/

So can someone please politely point me in the right direction?

Comment: what directory is your htaccess file in?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ folder/basic.php?url=$1 [L]
```

This is more of a problem with regexs than .htaccess files.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will explain using your htaccess.

> RewriteEngine on

Turn on the Rewrite Module to enable URL rewriting

> RewriteBase /folder

Rewrite the Base Directory to directory name `folder`

> RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ basic.php?url=$1 [L]

Remap every request make using the `folder/*****` to `basic.php?url=********`

<sub>Note: `RewriteEngine On` Should be the first statement on your case</sub>

Comment: you would only use `RewriteBase /folder` if this is in `DOCROOT/folder/.htaccess`, in which case you don't want the `folder/` in the rule regexp.  This rule will also loop.

Comment: @TeeryE, Absolutely. And InVert, just make sure you assign the rule, outside the folder directory